# Antimuon-electron interaction

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, interactions, weak-interaction, electroweak

I was wondering if the following interaction is possible:
$\mu^++e^-\to \bar{\nu_{\mu}}+\nu_e$

Clearly every conservation law is satisfied, including each lepton number conservation, but I can’t seem to find a possible Feynman diagram that satisfies lepton number conservation at each vertex.

I have read about family lepton number conservation violation, but I think that has to do with neutrino oscillations, and I think this interaction is not that case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use the weak force? You have that $e^- \to W^- + \nu_e$ and similarly for the antimuon.

Comment: But then $\mu^+\to W^++\bar{\nu_{\mu}}$ and the resulting $W^-$ and $W^+$ have to pair with something, right?

Comment: The answerer and comments all give you that required information, I would suggest thinking about it and deciding on accepting the answer if it solves your question. If it does not you should indicate why to them.

Answer (score 11):

This diagram can do it, satisfying lepton number conservation at each vertex:

[image]

Comment: Is charge conserved at each vertex? What charge does the W boson have?

Comment: The W is charged.

Comment: @cut depends on whether you draw it flying forward or backward in time, if it's emitted at the muonic vertex it's a $W^+$, if it's emitted at the electronic vertex it's a $W^-$. But since it's a virtual particle it's really the same, and a Lorentz boost will change one into the other.

Comment: One way to see it is: the positive muon emits a $W^+$, which is then absorbed by the negative electron, producing the neutral neutrino. Or, alternatively, the negative electron emits a $W^-$, which is absorbed by the positive muon, producing the neutral neutrino. Depending on how we order events in time, both are possible, that is why I did not specify the charge. For virtual particles this does not matter, as the commenter above has pointed out.