# Is it possible for an electron and antimuon to neutrinos?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, leptons

If i have an electron and an antimuon is it possible that they could annihilate into a electron neutrino and antimuon neutrino? Am i correct in saying both spin and charge are conserved in this reaction.

Comment: Duplication: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/741105/antimuon-electron-interaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process $e^- \mu^+ \to \nu_e \bar{\nu}_\mu$ is possible in the standard model (by exchange of a virtual $W^\pm$ boson). As for any allowed process, the total electromagnetic charge and the total angular momentum are conserved.

Comment: Awesome thanks, assuming I had no restriction on momentum do you think the decay above is more likely to happen than an electron an antimuon annihilating into a positron and muon?

Comment: @user2279603 1. As there are two particles in the initial state, this in NOT a decay process (in the latter, you would have only a single particle in the initial state). 2. The process $e^- \mu^+ \to e^+ \mu^-$ violates $L_e$ and $L_\mu$ being thus forbidden in the (minimal) standard model. 3. The word "annihilation" is misplaced in this context.